# Python: True fire-and-forget POST request without waiting for response even in separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, fire-and-forget

In Python 3.10, I want to send some data to an API Server using the POST method without waiting for response. I have seen many solutions which use a separate thread to make the POST request, but my requirement is not to wait for response **even in the separate thread**. I want a true fire-and-forget API where I am able to send the required data to the API and close the connection immediately. Let the API take its own time to process, and let no other resource on the client side get used in processing the response (not even in separate thread).

Is this possible?

Should I use a combination of separate thread and timeout (long enough just to send the data), or are there any caveats in this approach where some requests may not reach the server? Are there any better ways without using a sub-process or threading, either in my code or in any library's code?

I am okay to use a lower level library, if it allows just sending the data without handing or waiting for the response.

Comment: That's not how HTTP works, without a response how do you even know if your message reached the server? I think you need to change how the server side works, like doing `Connection: close`, `ignore_user_abort(true)` and `session_write_close();` in PHP and then continuing the PHP script execution without keeping the client locked waiting..

Comment: I am okay if the message does not reach the server once in a while. It's not a mission critical API, that's why I want it as fire and forget without using any more client side resources than necessary, a failure rate of 1-2% is okay. Is it not possible in HTTP?

Comment: I am okay with a minimum lower level response at the HTTP level that the data sent by the client is received by the server. But I don't want the actual response of the API. Is it possible without changing server side code?

Comment: You could try using sockets and sending the HTTP request manually like `GET /{path} HTTP/1.1\r\n` but I'm not sure what that entails, if there's handshakes involved (so you kinda wait for a response) or if the server might hang waiting to send you a response, I don't know.

Comment: This is a dirty trick (given your http module is thread-safe): you could create a global memory space (a list, or a dict) that will never be garbage collected, and one-shot that thread in there. That is, when the thread starts, append its reference to the global memory. When the thread is done, automatically remove it. If you want, use a global lock to synchronize access to that memory from all threads. This way, once you start that thread anywhere, you don't need to keep its reference in a local variable, as it will always be safe from the gc until it finishes executing (thus fire & forget).